# проблемы с запуском exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

написал прикольную игру на pygame, скомпилировал в exe. Но она запускается и сразу заканчивается! А если через IDLE открыть - все работает! Спасибо! Компилировал через pyinstaller. Windows 10.

```
#alien_invation.py

import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group
from settings import Settings
from game_stats import GameStats
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf
import sys
def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("'Инопланетное вторжение' от Антона Артюхова.")
    stats = GameStats(ai_settings)
    bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
    bullets = Group()
    aliens = Group()
    gf.create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)
    while True:
        if stats.game_active:
            ship.update()
            gf.update_bullets(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)
            gf.update_aliens(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)
        else:
            screen.fill ([0,0,0])
            f1 = pygame.font.Font(None, 100)
            text2 = f1.render('Game Over. ', 1, (255, 0, 255))
            screen.blit(text2, [400,400])
            f1 = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
            text2 = f1.render('Игра окончена. Но не переживайте, вместо вас уже летит 50 ракет. ', 1, (255, 255, 255))
            screen.blit(text2, [0,600])
            f1 = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
            text2 = f1.render('Они точно выиграют этих проклятых пришельцев! ', 1, (255, 255, 255))
            screen.blit(text2, [0,700])
            pygame.display.flip()
            print ('Ваш результат: ' + str (ai_settings.points) + ' очков.')
            file = open ('alien invation.txt','a')
            file.write (str (ai_settings.points) + '\n')
            file.close()
            file = open ('alien invation.txt','r')
            lines = file.readlines ()
            mylist = []
            for line in lines:
                line.replace ('\n','')
                mylist.append (int (line))
            file.close()
            print ('рекорд:' + str (max (mylist)))
            sys.exit()
        gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)
run_game ()
```

Comment: Укажите пожалуйста чем вы компилировали, какая у вас ОС, используете ли виртуальную среду и другие подробности. И приведите пример вашей программы.

Comment: Приведите код программы

Comment: Запустите приложение в консоли с ключами `--debug` и `-v`. В выводе скорее всего будет причина возникшей проблемы.

Comment: @Стас сделал код

Comment: @S.Nick сделал.

Comment: пример должен быть воспроизводимым.

Comment: @S.Nick да, но он работает!

Comment: Не установлены модули settings, game_stats, game_functions (в pip их нет, в интернете не искал). Ship устанавливается, но неправильно (это наверно мои проблемы)

Comment: @Стас это мои модули! Я их  создал! Но спасибо Вам за Ваши старания!

Comment: @Антон но так всё таки ?

Comment: @Александр что бы это значило...

Comment: Антон Вы сказали, что у вас проблемы с exe, потом вас попросили привести код. И вот он, код, но он не работает, т. к. некоторые файлы были написаны лично вами. И вы не сказали решена проблема или нет и не хотите привести недостающие файлы. Вот у вас и спрашивает @Александр, что все таки получилось или вы ещё чего то ждете

Comment: А какие флаги вы использовали для компиляции вашей игры? Чем пользуетесь? Sublime text?